# When doing an online assessment for a potential employer, is it expected to use resources on the web?

Tags: job-search, recruitment, tech-industry, test

A recruiter from a a large tech company is asking me to do an online assessment. It is timed and done through a website. There is a practice version of the test I have taken. I'm wondering if I'm allowed to use resources such as searching the internet for information? Before the test began it displayed an agreement (looked like a terms-of-service) that I had to accept. One of the terms was

> You agree that all work submitted will be made solely by yourself, and
>   you will not consult any third person or use any other resource.

Does this mean I'm not allowed to search things on the internet? OTOH there was advice saying not to open more than 3 tabs in the browser or the assessment may freeze, so it sort of sounded like they expected it.

I get the impression the recruiter I've been in touch with is dealing with a lot of different people and isn't particularly technical himself. Also the website the assessment is done through is a third party to the company I'm applying to, and a lot looks like boilerplate. I don't think asking the recruiter directly is the best idea because he probably doesn't know and might just say "no" to cover his ass.

EDIT: so if I can't remember the exact name of a function in a programming language or the order it takes its arguments, I can't look it up and couldn't complete the test? This seems opposite of what they were intending to test. (I have done similar tests in person where they said not to worry about typos or spelling mistakes but on the online environment it has to compile without errors)

EDIT 2: I am concerned that most other people would just use other resources without asking and this would put me at a disadvantage. Obviously they can't be stopped. How should I phrase the message to the recruiter?

> Hi, I'm wondering if any resources are allowed during the test, such
>   as the official documentation for the programming language or
>   Wikipedia articles?

Comment: We can't tell you what the answer to this question is, you need to ask the company you're doing the assessment for.

Comment: The requirement is clearly spelled out. "No other resource". We all know that's stupid on many, many levels. We also all know that cheating whatever software checks this requirement is stupid easy. But you will need to take this up with whoever wants the test that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so if I can't remember the exact name of a function in a programming
>   language or the order it takes its arguments, I can't look it up and
>   couldn't complete the test?

Whenever you don't know what is expected of you, it only makes sense to ask the one who has the answer.

While it seems obvious to me (and I could be wrong), I'm not the one interviewing. If you really don't understand the instructions, ask the recruiter if you are allowed to look things up or not. Then follow their directions.

> I don't think asking the recruiter directly is the best idea because
>   he probably doesn't know and might just say "no" to cover his ass.

If you were the only candidate this recruiter has ever asked to take such a test, you might be right. But almost certainly the recruiter has been asked this question.

Just ask.

Answer (score 10):

> or use any other resource

It's a pretty clear cut no.

Comment: Very clear cut. But at the same time there isn't anything to stop you doing it (other than the internet not being a very useful resource for online exams).

Comment: So if I can't remember how they spelled a function name I fail the test just like that?

Comment: Maybe? I have no idea, ask them that, I just answered the question.

Comment: @Synerna1 It's not likely they care about small little errors. They probably want to see your thought process. If you have concerns that the test may not show your true potential, you should take it up with them. But note that there are probably other candidates that won't complain and will just do it, so I'd make every effort to give it your best shot.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie "other candidates that won't complain and will just do it" I agree other candidates won't complain aka ask, and many will just use other resources and there's nothing stopping them. That is the point of my question.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie "They probably want to see your thought process" I agree, thing is the program won't compile (or crashes) and is given a set of automated tests to pass in the assessment